# Could not find the entry 'dummy'...EntrypointLookup.php

Tags: symfony

I have a strange problem...

I create a new Symfony project:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton Vikings
```

Then I installed encore (bootstrap, jquery, poppers.js)

```
composer require encore
yarn install
yarn add bootstrap --dev
yarn add jquery popper.js --dev
```

I setup app.js and app.scss for bootstrap and run:

```
yarn encore dev
```

Got 5 files:

```
public/build/app.css
public/build/app.js
public/build/entrypoints.json
public/build/manifest.json
public/build/runtime.js
public/build/vendors~app.js
```

but now when i run

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

got this error:

```
// Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true

 // Clearing outdated warmup directory...

 // Warming up cache...


In EntrypointLookup.php line 86:

  [Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Exception\EntrypointNotFoundException]
  Could not find the entry "dummy" in "/Users/lukahome/Projects/Vikings/public/build/entrypoints.json". Found: entrypoints.


Exception trace:
 () at /Users/lukahome/Projects/Vikings/vendor/symfony/webpack-encore-bundle/src/Asset/EntrypointLookup.php:86
 Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Asset\EntrypointLookup->validateEntryName() at /Users/lukahome/Projects/Vikings/vendor/symfony/webpack-encore-bundle/src/Asset/EntrypointLookup.php:59
 Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Asset\EntrypointLookup->getEntryFiles() at /Users/lukahome/Projects/Vikings/vendor/symfony/webpack-encore-bundle/src/Asset/EntrypointLookup.php:41
 Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Asset\EntrypointLookup->getJavaScriptFiles() at /Users/lukahome/Projects/Vikings/vendor/symfony/webpack-encore-bundle/src/CacheWarmer/EntrypointCacheWarmer.php:41
 Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\CacheWarmer\EntrypointCacheWarmer->doWarmUp() at /Users/lukahome/Projects/Vikings/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/CacheWarmer/AbstractPhpFileCacheWarmer.php:51
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\CacheWarmer\AbstractPhpFileCacheWarmer->warmUp() at /Users/lukahome/Projects/Vikings/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/CacheWarmer/CacheWarmerAggregate.php:96
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate->warmUp() at /Users/lukahome/Projects/Vikings/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php:194
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->warmup() at /Users/lukahome/Projects/Vikings/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php:129
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->execute() at /Users/lukahome/Projects/Vikings/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /Users/lukahome/Projects/Vikings/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:919
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /Users/lukahome/Projects/Vikings/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:89
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /Users/lukahome/Projects/Vikings/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:262
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /Users/lukahome/Projects/Vikings/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:75
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /Users/lukahome/Projects/Vikings/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:145
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /Users/lukahome/Projects/Vikings/bin/console:38
```

I debug a little and find that 'dummy' is hardcoded in EntrypointCacheWarmer.php

```
protected function doWarmUp($cacheDir, ArrayAdapter $arrayAdapter)
    {
        foreach ($this->cacheKeys as $cacheKey => $path) {
            // If the file does not exist then just skip past this entry point.
            if (!file_exists($path)) {
                continue;
            }

            $entryPointLookup = new EntrypointLookup($path, $arrayAdapter, $cacheKey);

            try {
                $entryPointLookup->getJavaScriptFiles('dummy');
            } catch (EntrypointNotFoundException $e) {
                // ignore exception
            }
        }
    }
```

If i change "dummy" to "app" there is no error, but I don't know if this is right solution...

PLEASE HELP

Comment: For now, the only "proper" solution is to downgrade `symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` from v1.2.0 to v1.1.0

Answer (score 3):

This may help: https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore-bundle/issues/47#issuecomment-468833014

Looks like they forgot to add:

```
use Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Exception\EntrypointNotFoundException;
```

to `Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\CacheWarmer\EntrypointCacheWarmer.php`.

Answer (score 2):

It's all fixed up in the latest release now! Just upgrade to v1.2.1. We'll add an integration test to cover this layer to avoid future problems.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem...
I guess it's a small oversight on the part of symfony.
I just renamed the app.js file to dummy.js and in the webpack.config.js until symfony fix it